# Is it possible to use the bivariate Coppersmith method in this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Is it possible to use the bivariate Coppersmith method in this polynomial?

$p(m,n)=675*m*n+297*m+25*n+11$

we can find $m0$ and $n0$ such that

$(675*m0*n0+297*m0+25*n0+11) (mod (1763)) = 0 $

Comment: That would depend – what is the bivariate Coppersmith method, and what exactly do you want to do to that polynomial (congruence)?

Comment: To find m0 and n0

Comment: I take it you mean $m_0$ and $n_0$, but I don't know what you mean by those symbols.

Comment: $(675*m0*n0+297*m0+25*n0+11) (mod (1763)) = 0 $

Comment: @GerryMyerson I corrected, thanks

Comment: The original paper on the method is Coppersmith, Don, Finding a Small Root of a Bivariate Integer Equation; Factoring with High Bits Known, Advances in Cryptology —EUROCRYPT ’96, Maurer, Ueli, Editor, pages 178--189. It might be possible to access it from https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-68339-9_16

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can't understand could you kindly explain the hypothesis to me in the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry – what exactly can't you understand?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Whether or not it can be used in my case and why

Comment: Have you looked at the Coppersmith paper, Alberico?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I have looked at it but it is written in a very complex way for me